# How can I get the widget that is tapped?

Tags: flutter, containers, touch

I have a grid like app that is variable number of rows and columns.  issue is to easily get the widget that the user taps on. I define a container for my each of the cells in my grid and add a tap handler that will return TapDownDetails which give me the globalPosition.dx and dy. I really want  the parent widget and yes I can build a list of offsets for all the widgets in the grid then dig the right one out of the list. I did this by building a list at afterlayout time:
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);

```
_afterLayout(_) {

int i = 0;
bb = new List<Offset>(keys.length);

this.keys.forEach((key) {
   RenderBox cell1 = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
     bb[i++] = cell1.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
});
```

I add the keys in my build code and hit test in my tapdown code. Now this works but surely I am missing the obvious and there is a better solution

my code

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  List<myCell> slots = new List<myCell>();
  bool inputMode = true;
  List<BE> BEs = new List<BE>();
  Map<int,List<int>> reserved ;
  int timeRows = 4;
  int court = 0;
  List<GlobalKey> keys = new List<GlobalKey>();
  List<Offset> bb =  List<Offset>();
  MyHomePage(){
    initState();
  }
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      inputMode = false;
      slots.add(new myCell(true,TypeBooking.Booked,TimeInterval.hour,1,6));
      court +=1;
      slots.add(new myCell(true,TypeBooking.Booked,TimeInterval.hour,timeRows*court*4+2,6));
      court +=1;
      slots.add(new myCell(true,TypeBooking.Booked,TimeInterval.hour,timeRows*court*4,6));
      court +=1;
      slots.add(new myCell(false,TypeBooking.Booked,TimeInterval.hour,timeRows*court*4,4));
      court +=1;
      slots.add(new myCell(true,TypeBooking.Booked,TimeInterval.hour,timeRows*court*4+2,6));
      slots.add(new myCell(true,TypeBooking.Maintainence,TimeInterval.hour,8,4));

      BEs.add(new BE(0,6));
      BEs.add(new BE(0,6));
      BEs.add(new BE(2,6));
      BEs.add(new BE(0,6));
      BEs.add(new BE(0,4));
      BEs.add(new BE(2,6));
      BEs.add(new BE(0,6));
      BEs.add(new BE(0,4));
      BEs.add(new BE(0,4));
      BEs.add(new BE(2,6));
      BEs.add(new BE(0,6));
      BEs.add(new BE(0,4));
      reserved = new  Map<int,List<int>>();
    });
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
  }
  void _toggleInput() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
  //    inputMode = !inputMode ;
      inputMode = true;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Globals.count = 0;
    Globals.hour = 8;
  //  slots.add(new myCell(true,false,TimeInterval.hour,0,6));

    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body:
      SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Row(
                  children: List.generate(
                    BEs.length,
                    (col) => Column(
                        children: List.generate(
                          4*4,
                          (row) => ProduceCell(inputMode,row,col,slots,BEs)
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
           ),
       )
    );
  }
  Widget  ProduceCell(bool inputMode,int row, int col,List<myCell> slots,List<BE> BEs)
  {
    double borderwidth = 1;
    Color mycolor;
    String label;
    Globals.countperColumn += 1;
    int remain = Globals.countperColumn % 4;
    var bottomstyle = remain == 0? BorderStyle.solid : BorderStyle.none;
    var key = GlobalKey();
    keys.add(key);
    var con =  GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            inputMode = !inputMode;
          });
        },
      child: Container(
        //draw border
        key:  key,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(

        border: Border(

        right: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
    bottom: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.black, width: borderwidth, style: bottomstyle)
  )
  ),

  width: 150,
  height: 60,
//child is empty container or a textbox

  )
  //     color: Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0));


  );


  return con;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you wrap each widget in a `GestureDetector` and assign an index to each one so you can easily know which one is being tapped without much complexity?

Comment: needs more focus and clarity so the problem can be solved, currently implemented code aswell

Comment: I wrapped my container in a gestureDetector and the tap handler does not have a reference to anything other than the  containing _MyHomePageState object. this is the issue I am facing no matter where the tap handler is placed. i ediited my question to provide all the code